# Chrome/Firefox inline-blocks inside variable-width wrapper. Firefox does not variate the width

Tags: css

[This is the jsFiddle for this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/ovdsm3jv/).

Changing the width on Chrome 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit) (Mac) makes the black squares (`.Selector-item`) hide as the `.Selector-viewport` element changes widths. Like shown in the following images:

[image: Chrome big width]
[image: Chrome small width]

However, on Firefox 34.0.5 (Mac), the right column gets pushed, overflowing the frame and not variating the width of the `.Selector-viewport` element:

[image: FF big width]
[image: FF small width]

How can I ensure that the same behaviour that Chrome exhibits is consistent across browsers?

### Code

#### HTML

```
<div class="Columns">
    <div class="Column-1">
        <div class="Selector">
            <div class="Selector-viewport">
                <div class="Selector-wrapper">
                    <div class="Selector-item"></div>
                    <div class="Selector-item"></div>
                    <div class="Selector-item"></div>
                    <div class="Selector-item"></div>
                    <div class="Selector-item"></div>
                    <div class="Selector-item"></div>
                    <div class="Selector-item"></div>
                    <div class="Selector-item"></div>
                    <div class="Selector-item"></div>
                    <div class="Selector-item"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Column-2">
        <p>Column 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.Columns {
    display: flex;
}
.Column-1 {
    flex: 1 1 66.6667%;
    background: red;
}
.Column-2 {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    background: blue;
}

.Selector {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 58px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.Selector-viewport {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.Selector-wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.Selector-item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 30px;
    height: 60px;
    white-space: normal;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: black;
}
```

## Thank you

Note: I can't have the items floated and wrapping on two lines. They need to be on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Flex model still has limited support in browsers and can cause undesired results.

I have changed the flex model to a relative one using positioning as below. This should solbe your issue.

### DEMO

Try adding width to the element you wish to overflow:

```
.Columns {
    position:relative;
}
.Column-1 {
    margin-right:100px;
    background: red;
}
.Column-2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

To make it variable use a percentage or min/max width.

Comment: This seems to display some responsiveness, but it still pushes the right column on firefox when you keep making the frame smaller

Comment: You need to set width to the parent elements too. Is the right column to be fixed width?

Comment: Yes the right column is fixed width. Could you update the fiddle with your solution? Thanks

Comment: @AlainJacometForte Change answer above to accomodate. Hope this helps.